# Determine the value of $\theta$.

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-calculus, variance, discrete-calculus

Given two random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ with pdf
$$
f\left(x_i\right)= \begin{cases}\frac{1}{2 \theta}, & -\theta<x_i<\theta \\ 0, & x_i \text { otherwise }\end{cases}
$$
If it is known that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent and $\operatorname{Var}\left(X_1 X_2\right)=\frac{64}{9}$, determine the value of $\theta$.

My working:
If the random variable X comes from continuous data with pdf

$$\operatorname{Var}\left(X_1 X_2\right)=\frac{64}{9}$$
$$\operatorname{Var}\left(X_1 X_2\right)=\int(x-\mu)^2f(x) dx$$
for $\mu$ is the expected value. For example
$$\mu=\int xf(x) dx$$
if subtitute $f(x)=\frac{1}{2 \theta}$, thus
$$\mu=\int x\frac{1}{2 \theta} dx$$
$$\mu=\frac{x^2}{4 \theta}+C$$
So
$$\operatorname{Var}\left(X_1 X_2\right)=\int(x-\mu)^2f(x) dx$$
$$\operatorname{Var}\left(X_1 X_2\right)=\int(x-\frac{x^2}{4 \theta})^2\frac{1}{2 \theta} dx$$
$$\operatorname{Var}\left(X_1 X_2\right)=\int(x^2-\frac{x^3}{2 \theta}+\frac{x^4}{16 \theta})\frac{1}{2 \theta} dx$$
$$\frac{64}{9}=(\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{2x^4}{\theta}+\frac{5x^5}{16 \theta})\frac{1}{2 \theta}$$
$$\frac{64}{9}=(\frac{x^3}{6 \theta}-\frac{x^4}{\theta^2}+\frac{5x^5}{32 \theta})$$

How the next step and please correct if i'm wrong for my work. Thank u

Comment: The integrals should be between $-\theta$ and $\theta$.

Comment: Please do not delete questions when someone has spent time and effort to comment or answer. It is disrespectful to those who have helped. The answers might also be useful to future users.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your own question by changing the title and removing essential parts of the question. This removes the relevance of the answers and the usefulness of the question to future users.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $EX_1 = EX_2 = 0$, hence
$$
\begin{align}
Var (X_1 X_2) &= E(X_1X_2)^2 - \left(E\left(X_1X_2\right)\right)^2 \\
&= EX_1^2 EX_2^2 - (EX_1 EX_2)^2 \\
&=(EX_1^2)^2 \\
&= \left(\int_{-\theta}^\theta\frac{x^2}{2\theta}  dx\right)^2 \\
&= \left(\frac{\theta^2}{3}\right)^2 \\
\end{align}
$$
Solve equatioin $\left(\frac{\theta^2}{3}\right)^2 = \frac{64}9$,
derive $\theta = 2\sqrt2$

Answer (score 1):

As shown in xzm's answer, the variance can be obtained by using the independence of $X_1$ and $X_2$. We can also compute the distribution of $X_1X_2$. This approach might be closer to that of the OP.

---

**Compute the Distribution of the Product**

The distribution of $(X_1,X_2)$ is uniform on $[-\theta,\theta]\times[-\theta,\theta]$, but the distribution of $X_1X_2$ is not uniform on $\left[-\theta^2,\theta^2\right]$.

In the case for $\lambda\ge0$,

[image]

The shaded area is
$$
2\theta^2+2\lambda-2\lambda\log\left(\frac{|\lambda|}{\theta^2}\right)\tag1
$$
In the case for $\lambda\lt0$:

[image]

The shaded area is also given by $(1)$. Since the area of the whole space is $4\theta^2$, we get
$$
P(X_1X_2\le\lambda)=\frac12+\frac\lambda{2\theta^2}-\frac\lambda{2\theta^2}\log\left(\frac{|\lambda|}{\theta^2}\right)\tag2
$$
$(2)$ gives a density of
$$
-\frac1{2\theta^2}\log\left(\frac{|\lambda|}{\theta^2}\right)\tag3
$$

---

**Compute the Variance**

The distribution is an even function, so the mean of $X_1X_2$ is $0$:
$$
\begin{align}
E(X_1X_2)
&=-\int_{-\theta^2}^{\theta^2}\frac\lambda{2\theta^2}\log\left(\frac{|\lambda|}{\theta^2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}\lambda\tag{4a}\\
&=0\tag{4b}
\end{align}
$$
and the mean of $(X_1X_2)^2$ is
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{E}\!\left((X_1X_2)^2\right)
&=-\int_{-\theta^2}^{\theta^2}\frac{\lambda^2}{2\theta^2}\log\left(\frac{|\lambda|}{\theta^2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}\lambda\tag{5a}\\
&=-\theta^4\int_0^1t^2\log(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{5b}\\
&=\frac{\theta^4}9\tag{5c}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the variance is
$$
\begin{align}
\mathrm{Var}(X_1X_2)
&=\mathrm{E}\!\left((X_1X_2)^2\right)-\mathrm{E}(X_1X_2)^2\tag{6a}\\
&=\frac{\theta^4}9\tag{6b}
\end{align}
$$

---

**Answer to the Question**

Since the formula for the variance matches xzm's answer, the value of $\theta$ also matches:
$$
\frac{\theta^4}9=\frac{64}9\implies\theta=2\sqrt2\tag7
$$